# iOS - Account Deletion for trial accounts

Tags: ios, app-store

The appstore guidelines states, "If your app supports account creation, you must also offer account deletion within the app."
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#5.1.1

My app only needs the name and email address of the user for the sign up process. The name is only for greetings; so maybe I can bring it down to just the email address.

Assume the app gives a free trial of a service for 30 days or so. How can I prevent the same user from signing up again for free trial once the account deletion is implemented?

Is soft delete an option here? How would apple know if we are actually deleting account data or just soft-deleting it?

Comment: First of all, how do you create accounts? Is it just data stored on your backend server? If so, I guess the answer is only matter of your backend implementation. Like, send another API request, when the user deletes their account and handle this information whichever way you like – a very common client-server problem. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: When you delete an account you could generate a hash of the email using, say SHA512 and store this  (make sure to strip periods (.) from the email address and convert it to lower case before hashing otherwise people can simply change the case of their email to get around it)  Then, when someone tries to sign up again you can hash their email and see if you already have it in the deleted list .  If so, let them sign up but without the trial.  Of course, if this is a paid service delivered in the app then you need to use IAP.  IAP can manage free trials for you